# Unablet to create Postgresql index due to pending trigger events

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to load a SQL file dumped from Sqlite3 into Postgresql 10, but the load fails when it encounters any `CREATE INDEX` statements with the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot CREATE INDEX "<table_name>" because it has pending trigger events
```

I can find any useful results in Google, as most people who encounter this error do so during migrations, not a bulk load into an empty database. Since all commands in the SQL file are in a single transaction, this error aborts the entire load.

How do I fix this error?